# assert_select not working after upgrading to latest rails version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following HTML snippet, and my `assert_select` is no longer working (after upgrading to the latest version of Rails):

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="foo">
      <h2><a href="/downloads/latest.zip">Latest</a></h2>
      <p>
        <a href="/downloads/latest.zip" class="button download">
          <span>Download</span>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Here's the assertion:

`assert_select '.container a.downloadbutton[href^=/downloads]', assigns(:downloads).count`

Here's the error:

`Expected exactly 1 element matching ".container a.button[href^='/downloads']", found 0.`

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!!
 V

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mismatch in the class between the classes in the code fragment 'button' and 'download' and the class in the assertion 'downloadbutton'.  Perhaps getting rid of the space between 'button' and 'download' in the fragment will work.